how to correct the error i get while downloading gromacs on ubuntu 22.04
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: unsafe srcdir value: '/home/banerjee/gromacs 1/gromacs-2024.2/build/src/external/build-fftw/fftwBuild-prefix/src/fftwBuild'
make[2]: *** [src/external/build-fftw/CMakeFiles/fftwBuild.dir/build.make:92: src/external/build-fftw/fftwBuild-prefix/src/fftwBuild-stamp/fftwBuild-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3532: src/external/build-fftw/CMakeFiles/fftwBuild.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2


You should contact the upstream developer of this software, because it looks like it's got some issues in the code.  This also isn't clear where you got the software from, what it is, etc. which makes some other problems.

Yeah this is not "while downloading" it's "while building" - the first thing I'd try is renaming your /home/banerjee/gromacs 1 directory to something without a space in it (like /home/banerjee/gromacs_1 for example).

... also fyi gromacs software is available from the Ubuntu universe repository (and looks fairly up to date - version 2023.3-1ubuntu3 in Ubuntu 24.04)
